# Plugin was not found error during gradle build

Tags: gradle

When trying to add the [org.ajoberstar.grgit](https://login.gradle.org/plugin/org.ajoberstar.grgit/2.3.0) plugin into my gradle build, I get the following error:

```
Plugin [id: 'org.ajoberstar.grgit', version: '2.3.0'] was not found in any of 
the following sources:

- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
- Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 
 'org.ajoberstar.grgit:org.ajoberstar.grgit.gradle.plugin:2.3.0')
  Searched in the following repositories:
    Gradle Central Plugin Repository
```

Here is my code:

```
import org.ajoberstar.grgit.*

buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.ajoberstar:grgit:2.3.0'
    }
}

plugins {
    id "org.sonarqube" version "2.6"
    id "idea"
    id "org.ajoberstar.grgit" version "2.3.0"
}

// ...
```

Any idea on how to solve this? Can I somehow manually download the plugin and put it into the cache?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to either use:

```
plugins {
    id "org.ajoberstar.grgit" version "2.3.0"
}
```

or:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.ajoberstar:grgit:2.3.0'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'org.ajoberstar.grgit'
```

Comment: Yes, and I already did the first version. Tried the second one as well but that didn't fix it.

Comment: @FlorianBaierl it seems strange, should work exactly the same.

Comment: The second version also didn't work for me, but the first did - thanks.  Gradle has been a really terrible experience compared to Maven.

Comment: In my company if i use first version., we need to configure proxy. If i use second version working fine without proxy. Why first version allways required proxy?

Answer (score 1):

I am not entirely sure why, but it started working all of a sudden. 
Here is what I tried:

- I had "C:/Program Files/..." in my JAVA_OPTS environment variable and replaced that with "C:/Programme/..." (German localization)
- restarted my PC

After that it magically worked. I am pretty sure it has something to do with the companies proxies and some custom scripts for it (my best guess is that it didn't handle the space character in the JAVA_HOME variable well).

Comment: Prompted by this answer I checked my network and even though I'm not going through a company proxy, I was connected through a different network interface to a mobile hotspot. Disconnecting from the hotspot and using standard broadband without any VPN setup has seemed to do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Check the SSH handshake. In my case, I had to remove the following entries from my ~/.gradle/gradle.properties file, which was causing it to fail to connect securely to our corporate artifactory:

```
# systemProp.javax.net.ssl.trustStore=/etc/ssl/certs/java/cacerts
# systemProp.javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=changeit
```